# Add text to image in loop swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory, memory-management, uiimage

I am adding text to an array of images using swift. Below is my code for the loop:

```
var holderClass = HolderClass()
var newImages = [UIImage]()
var counter = 0
for (index, oldImage) in holderClass.oldImages.enumerated(){
        let newImage = drawTextAtLoaction(text: "testing", image: oldImage)
        newImages[index] = newImage
        counter+=1
        if(counter == self.storyModule.getImageCount()){
            completionHandler(newImages)
        }
}
```

Here is the adding text function:

```
func drawTextAtLoaction(text: String, image: UIImage) -> UIImage{
    let textColor = UIColor.white
    let textFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 12)!
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)

    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: textFont,
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: textColor,
        ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]
    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))
    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: image.size)
    text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    if newImage != nil{
        return newImage!
    }else{
        return image
    }
}
```

Intuitively this loop should take constant storage, however, as shown by the following image it takes linear storage and causes memory errors with larger numbers of images.

[image: Allocation instrument]

How can I use constant memory for such an operation?

edit: I think that I may have oversimplified this a bit. The oldImages array is really an array of images inside an object. So the initialization of old images looks as so.

```
class HolderClass{
    private var oldImages: [UIImage]!
    init(){
      oldImages = [UIImage(), UIImage()]
    }
}
```

edit 2:
This is how the image data is loaded. The following code is in viewDidLoad.

```
var holderClass = HolderClass()
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    var dataIntermediate = [StoryData]()
    let dataRequest:NSFetchRequest<StoryData> = StoryData.fetchRequest()
    do {
        dataIntermediate = try self.managedObjectContext.fetch(dataRequest)
        for storyData in dataIntermediate{
            var retrievedImageArray = [UIImage]()
            if let loadedImage = DocumentSaveManager.loadImageFromPath(imageId: Int(storyData.id)){
                retrievedImageArray.append(loadedImage)
            }
            holderData.oldImages = retrievedImageArray
        }
    }catch{
        print("Failed to load data \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

This is the DocumentSaveManager class.

```
static func documentDirectoryURL() -> URL {
    let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    return documentsURL
}

static func saveInDocumentsDirectory(foldername:String, filename: String) -> URL {
    let fileURL = documentDirectoryURL().appendingPathComponent(foldername).appendingPathComponent(filename)
    return fileURL
}

static func loadImageFromPath(moduleId: Int, imageId: Int) -> UIImage? {
    let path = saveInDocumentsDirectory(foldername: String(describing: moduleId), filename: String(describing: imageId)).path
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
    if image == nil {
        return nil // Remember to alert user
    }
    return image
}
```

Comment: Can you post the declaration for `oldImages`?

Comment: @Adrian yes, I just edited it

Comment: The code you posted for your HolderClass doesn't compile. You need a `()` at the end of init. Additionally, how do you know they're old images if you're not feeding the initializer anything to evaluate?

Comment: @Adrian yes, I fixed the problem with the init. The array is populated with images from the documents directory, on viewdidload.

Comment: Without seeing all of your code, it's tough to see what's going on. From a physics for poets standpoint, I'd experiment with making refs weak so you deallocate things when you don't need them.

Comment: @Adrian is this enough. Thanks.